# How to make BuddyBuild call react-native bundle with --dev false

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, buddy-build

We are using BuddyBuild for our CI flow. When doing a build, I've noticed in the BuddyBuild log screen that it calls "react-native bundle" without the --dev false flag like so:
[image]

This means the main.jsbundle is being generated is for dev purposes. But this is a production build.

How can I tell BuddyBuild to add the --dev false flag to the bundle command?

Comment: Hi there - this is not something we support, but I'd be more than happy to forward this suggestion to our team. Can I ask what you were trying to achieve?